# redirect to new page when i click on Cancel button in C# (webpart)

Tags: c#

```
// Cancel button
            tc = new TableCell();
            btnCancel = new Button();
            btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler (btnCanel_Click ) ;
            tc.Controls.Add(btnCancel);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);

            t.Controls.Add(tr);


            // Empty table cell
            tr = new TableRow();
            tc = new TableCell();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);

            this.Controls.Add(t);
        }

        protected void btnCanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What i am tring to do is . when i click on Cancel button it redirect me to "Example.aspx".
i am create a webpart using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you want, on the server, would be [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). There is no need to postback though.  There are a few client side solutions.  Use a LinkButton, w/ onclick html attribute set to false.  My recommendation is something like this though:

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Cancel" ONCLICK="window.location.href='http://www.yourdomain.com/example.aspx'">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnCanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("example.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Aww, you didn't have to do that, it ruined my joke! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call the [HttpResponse.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) Method.

Example:

```
Response.Redirect("Example.aspx");
```