# redirect to new page when i click on Cancel button in C# (webpart)

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect to new page when i click on Cancel button in C# (webpart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430379/redirect-to-new-page-when-i-click-on-cancel-button-in-c-webpart)

```
        tc = new TableCell();
        btnCancel = new Button();
        btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        btnCancel.Click += new EventHandler (btnCanel_Click ) ;
        tc.Controls.Add(btnCancel);
        tr.Controls.Add(tc);

        t.Controls.Add(tr);


        // Empty table cell
        tr = new TableRow();
        tc = new TableCell();
        tr.Controls.Add(tc);

        this.Controls.Add(t);
    }

    protected void btnCanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

What i am tring to do is . when i click on Cancel button it redirect me to "Example.aspx".
i am create a webpart using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event handler, you should be able to do something as simple as:

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Response.Redirect("Example.aspx");
}
```

If I were building a WebPart though, I would make the redirect URL a parameter so that you can re-use the control:

```
public class YourWebPart
{
    public string CancelUrl { get; set; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // Build the part
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.Redirect(CancelUrl ?? "Example.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted this not half an hour ago and got three answers already.

[redirect to new page when i click on Cancel button in C# (webpart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430379/redirect-to-new-page-when-i-click-on-cancel-button-in-c-webpart)

Comment: Seems more of a comment. Also to be fair your answer was correctly formatted unlike Bala's.